# How to convert an audio file(mp3 file) into binary using java and the reverese?

Tags: java, audio, binary, stringbuilder

I want to process the **binary data** of an **audio file** and with the **processed binary data** I'd like to generate **a new audio file**.
I've converted the audio file into binary using the following code

```
            BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("song.mp3"));
            for (int i; (i = is.read()) != -1;) {
                String temp = "0000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(i).toUpperCase();
                if (temp.length() == 1) {
                    sb.append('0');
                }
                temp = temp.substring(temp.length() - 8); 
                sb.append(temp);
            }
```

I don't have any idea to create the audio file with the above binary data stored in the **sb**(StringBuilder) object.

Comment: My actual requirement is to develop audio steganography. I thought strings will be easier to process and apply LSB algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The following example convert some numbers (which could be the content of your audio file) into binary numbers forth and back:

```
public class Main
{

    private static String toBin(int i)
    {
        String temp = "00000000" + Integer.toBinaryString(i);
        return temp.substring((temp.length() - 8)).toUpperCase();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] inputData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        // Fill the buffer with binary numbers
        for (int x : inputData)
        {
            String binaryNumber = toBin(x);
            System.out.println("x="+x+", binaryNumber=" + binaryNumber);
            sb.append(binaryNumber);
        }

        // Print the whole buffer content
        System.out.println("sb=" + sb.toString());

        // Split the buffer into chunks of 8 characters
        for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i += 8)
        {
            String part = sb.substring(i, i + 8);

            // Convert back to integer
            int x = Integer.parseInt(part, 2);

            System.out.println("part=" + part + ", x=" + x);
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
x=1, binaryNumber=00000001
x=2, binaryNumber=00000010
x=3, binaryNumber=00000011
x=4, binaryNumber=00000100
x=5, binaryNumber=00000101
x=6, binaryNumber=00000110
x=7, binaryNumber=00000111
x=8, binaryNumber=00001000
x=9, binaryNumber=00001001
x=10, binaryNumber=00001010
sb=00000001000000100000001100000100000001010000011000000111000010000000100100001010
part=00000001, x=1
part=00000010, x=2
part=00000011, x=3
part=00000100, x=4
part=00000101, x=5
part=00000110, x=6
part=00000111, x=7
part=00001000, x=8
part=00001001, x=9
part=00001010, x=10
```

Comment: You're using `public static int parseInt(java.lang.String, int)` method to convert the binary numbers to Integer. How can I do the same for my audio file?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your problem, do you not know how to read binary (audio) files?

Comment: I converted the audio file(mp3) into binary using the above program that I've provided. But how can I reverse the logic?
With the binary values, how should I get my audio (mp3) file back?

Comment: My example above does both, the conversion into your binary string and then back to the original values. You just need to write the values of "x" into a file instead of printing to the screen.

Comment: In your case, the 'x' is a primitive Integer. But in mine the 'x' is not a primitive it's an audio file

Comment: No that is wrong. x is one byte from the binary file. i have the impression that you did not understand your own question.

Comment: `int[] inputData = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`
You're using primitive int array here so that you are able to convert each value into binary and also reverse it using `Integer.parseInt()` method. How can I do the same for an audio file? Do you have any user-defined method like `Audio.parseAudio()` (lol) for me??

Comment: You will find lots of instruction here and on other website that explain how to read and write files. My example above focuses on the processing of the content. Giving a complete example does ot make sense, you must learn such things yourself or will never be able to program.

Comment: okay, thanks. But my question is not about file handling. My doubt is about processing audio files in java.

Comment: You should start over with a clear description what you want to do. Then you may get a clear answer.

Comment: Okay, Stefan. Thank you so much for your help.